# Ionic 4: ion-textarea setfocus not set cursor at last position of text

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using ionic4 ion-textarea -

```
Html ->
<ion-textarea rows="2" cols="3" [(ngModel)]="wareHouseTxt" #houseTextArea
            (ngModelChange)="changeButtonStatus()" maxlength="4">
 <span class="shortcut-button">F9</span>
</ion-textarea>
TS -> 
@ViewChild('houseTextArea', null) houseTextArea: IonTextarea;
this.houseTextArea.setFocus();
```

As per above code focus is set inside textarea but cursor is placed at wrong position. For ref please check image -
[image]

Question - How to set cursor at last position of text.?(ionic 4)

Comment: not sure why that is behaving like that, but try using `this. houseTextArea.nativeElement.focus();` this should solve ur issue

Comment: thanks for answer... but it won't works because i am using IonTextArea not ElementRef to get nativeElement

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very old bug in Ionic. I sorted it out as follows:

COMPONENT CLASS:

```js
@ViewChild('houseTextArea') houseTextArea: IonTextarea;

async setTextCursor() {
 let inputEle = await this.houseTextArea.getInputElement();
 inputEl.setSelectionRange(this.wareHouseTxt.length,this. wareHouseTxt.length);
}
```

COMPONENT TEMPLATE:

```html
<ion-textarea rows="2" cols="3" [(ngModel)]="wareHouseTxt" #houseTextArea
            (ngModelChange)="changeButtonStatus()" maxlength="4" (ionFocus)='setTextCursor()'>
 <span class="shortcut-button">F9</span>
</ion-textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is fixed by wrapping the ion-input or ion-textarea inside an ion-item. check out discussion here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/9960#issuecomment-271998988

Comment: Just tried, somehow the cursor is still set to the beginning even if I put it inside a ion-item.